# Increasing validation loss from the very beginning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I've been doing a very simply binary cat/dog classification project with machine learning. I understand the problem of overfitting, but what's strange in my case is that the validation loss begins to rise from the very beginning. I've tried many different sets of hyperparameters, with L2 regularization, learning rate decay and stochastic gradient descent, and a large training set, but the issue remained. Here is the learning graph from one of the trials (the horizontal axis should be per 10 epochs):

[image: Learning graph 1]

The hyperparameters are: two hidden layers with 50 and 10 units, initial alpha = 0.05, alpha decay rate = 0.95 per 50 epochs, mini-batch size = 64, lambda = 0.05

Here are other sample learning graphs:
[image: Learning graph 2]

[image: Learning graph 3]

I developed my model on the basis of what's provided in Andrew Ng's Deep Learning Specialization, so I didn't expect many bugs. My full code, as required, is attached below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from scipy import special

#Data Preprocessing (the same for dev set, which I omit here)
path = '/Users/bobby/Downloads/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a/PetImages'
train_set = []
img_size = 80
categories = ['dogs_train','cats_train']
epsilon = 1e-8

for category in categories:
    path_animal = os.path.join(path, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path_animal):
        try:
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_animal, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            new_img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size, img_size))
            flattened_img_array = new_img_array.reshape(img_size*img_size)
            train_set.append([flattened_img_array, categories.index(category)])
        except:
            continue

import random
random.shuffle(train_set)

X_train = []
Y_train = []
for sample in train_set:
    X_train.append(sample[0])
    Y_train.append(sample[1])

X_train = (np.array(X_train).T)/255
Y_train = np.array(Y_train).reshape((1, np.array(Y_train).shape[0]))

def create_mini_batches(X, Y, mini_batch_size):
    m = X.shape[1]
    mini_batches = []
    num_mini_batches = m // mini_batch_size
    
    permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
    shuffled_X = X[:, permutation]
    shuffled_Y = Y[:, permutation]
    
    for i in range(num_mini_batches):
        select_X = shuffled_X[:, mini_batch_size*i : mini_batch_size*(i+1)]
        select_Y = shuffled_Y[:, mini_batch_size*i : mini_batch_size*(i+1)]
        mini_batch = (select_X, select_Y)
        mini_batches.append(mini_batch)
    
    if m % mini_batch_size != 0:
        last_X = shuffled_X[:, mini_batch_size*num_mini_batches:m]
        last_Y = shuffled_Y[:, mini_batch_size*num_mini_batches:m]
        last_mini_batch = (last_X, last_Y)
        mini_batches.append(last_mini_batch)
        
    return mini_batches

def initialize_parameters(layers_dims): 
    L = len(layers_dims) # number of layers (including input layer), in this case L=4.
    parameters = {}
    for l in range(1,L): # range(1,4).
        parameters['W' + str(l)] = np.random.randn(layers_dims[l],layers_dims[l-1]) * np.sqrt(2/layers_dims[l-1])
        parameters['b' + str(l)] = np.zeros((layers_dims[l],1))
    return parameters

def sigmoid(Z):
    A = special.expit(Z)
    return A,Z

def relu(Z):
    A = np.maximum(0.01*Z, Z)
    return A,Z

def forward_propagation(X, parameters):

    caches = [] #list containing Z for every node
    A = X
    L = int(len(parameters)/2)
    
    for l in range(1,L):
        A_prev = A
        W = parameters['W'+str(l)]
        b = parameters['b'+str(l)]
        Z = np.dot(W, A_prev) + b
        A, activation_cache = relu(Z) #activation_cache contains z[l].
        linear_cache = (A_prev, W, b) #linear_cache contains A[l-1], W[l], b[l].
        cache = (linear_cache, activation_cache)
        caches.append(cache)
    
    W = parameters['W'+str(L)]
    b = parameters['b'+str(L)]
    Z = np.dot(W, A) + b
    AL, activation_cache = sigmoid(Z)
    linear_cache = (A, W, b)
    cache = (linear_cache, activation_cache)
    caches.append(cache)
    
    return AL, caches

def compute_cost(AL, Y, parameters, lambd):
    m = Y.shape[1] # number of examples
    L = int(len(parameters)/2) #[6400,100,20,1] L=3 (0,1,2)
    reg_cost = 0
    
    for l in range(L):
        W = parameters['W' + str(l+1)]
        reg_cost += np.sum(np.square(W))
        
    J = (-1/m)*(np.sum(Y*np.log(AL+epsilon)+(1-Y)*np.log(1-AL+epsilon))) + (1/m) * (lambd/2) * reg_cost
    J = np.squeeze(J)
    return J

def linear_backward(dZ, linear_cache, lambd):
    A_prev, W, b = linear_cache
    m = A_prev.shape[1]
    
    dW = (1/m) * np.dot(dZ,A_prev.T) + (lambd/m)*W
    db = (1/m) * np.sum(dZ,axis=1,keepdims=True)
    dA_prev = np.dot(W.T,dZ)
    
    return dA_prev, dW, db

def relu_gradient(Z):
    dZ = np.where(Z > 0, 1, 0.01) 
    return dZ

def sigmoid_gradient(Z):
    dZ = special.expit(Z)*(1-special.expit(Z))
    return dZ

def linear_activation_backward(dA, cache, lambd, A, Y, activation):
    linear_cache, activation_cache = cache
    
    if activation == 'relu':
        dZ = dA * relu_gradient(activation_cache)
        dA_prev, dW, db = linear_backward(dZ, linear_cache, lambd)
        
    elif activation == 'sigmoid':
        dZ = A - Y
        dA_prev, dW, db = linear_backward(dZ, linear_cache, lambd)

    return dA_prev, dW, db

def L_model_backward(AL, Y, caches, lambd):
    grads = {}
    L = len(caches)
    m = AL.shape[1]
    Y = Y.reshape(AL.shape) 
        
    cache_final_layer = caches[L-1]
    grads["dA" + str(L-1)], grads["dW" + str(L)], grads["db" + str(L)] = linear_activation_backward(_, cache_final_layer, lambd, AL, Y, activation='sigmoid')
    
    for l in reversed(range(L-1)):
        current_cache = caches[l]
        grads["dA" + str(l)], grads["dW" + str(l+1)], grads["db" + str(l+1)] = linear_activation_backward(grads['dA' + str(l+1)], current_cache, lambd, _, _, activation='relu')
    
    return grads

def update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate):
    L = len(parameters) // 2
    for l in range(L):
        parameters["W" + str(l+1)] = parameters["W" + str(l+1)] - learning_rate * grads["dW" + str(l+1)]
        parameters["b" + str(l+1)] = parameters["b" + str(l+1)] - learning_rate * grads["db" + str(l+1)]
    return parameters

def Neural_Network_Model(X_train, Y_train, X_dev, Y_dev, layers_dims, learning_rate, num_epoch, mini_batch_size, lambd, k):
    
    mini_batches = create_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, mini_batch_size) #[(X{1},Y{1}),(X{2},Y{2}),...,(X{n},Y{n})]
    
    costs_train = []
    costs_dev = []
    parameters = initialize_parameters(layers_dims)
    
    AL_dev, caches_dev = forward_propagation(X_dev, parameters)
    J_dev = compute_cost(AL_dev, Y_dev, parameters, 0)
    costs_dev.append(J_dev)
    
    for i in range(num_epoch):
        for mini_batch in mini_batches:
            (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = mini_batch 
            AL, caches = forward_propagation(minibatch_X, parameters)
            J_train = compute_cost(AL, minibatch_Y, parameters, lambd)
            grads = L_model_backward(AL, minibatch_Y, caches, lambd)
            parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
        if i % 10 == 0:
            costs_train.append(J_train)
            AL_dev, caches_dev = forward_propagation(X_dev, parameters)
            J_dev = compute_cost(AL_dev, Y_dev, parameters, 0)
            costs_dev.append(J_dev)           
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" %(i, J_train))
            learning_rate = learning_rate * (k**(i/50))
            
    plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs_train),'r')
    plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs_dev),'b')
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('epochs (per thirties)')
    plt.show()
    
    return parameters, costs_train, costs_dev

parameters_updated, costs_train, costs_dev = Neural_Network_Model(X_train, Y_train, X_dev, Y_dev, [6400, 50, 10, 1], 0.05, 1000, 64, 0.05, 0.95)
```

I would really be grateful for anyone who is patient enough to read through my code. If the problem is still overfitting, could you offer some advice as to how to address this issue? I'm at a loss here because the validation loss goes up at a very early stage, so early stopping would cause underfitting by preventing the model from learning more deeply. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: @GerryP I've attached my code, could you kindly take a look?

Answer (score 0):

When Validation Loss starts to increase in early beginning like images you added, it means that there's there is something wrong in the model.
It's not clear what's it as you didn't show your model.

You could check the following links that will help you:

- Basic Cats vs Dogs [Detailed Example in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/Course%202%20-%20Part%202%20-%20Lesson%202%20-%20Notebook.ipynb)
- Detailed explanation for [Over-fitting in TF Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit)

or add your full code

Comment: I've attached my code, could you kindly take a look?

Comment: May I know why you are not using tensorflow?

Comment: I didn't use tf because Andrew Ng wants us to better understand the algorithm itself before using more sophisticated framework, and it turns out there is indeed something wrong in my understanding. I think the backprop part is the most prone to error, so could you specifically have a look at that part if my entire code is too long to read?